# Solving $2\times 2$ system of congruence using elimination

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let us suppose we have following system

$${5x+7y}\equiv 3\pmod {9}.$$

$${6x+5y}\equiv 4\pmod {9}.$$

I need to solve this task  using elimination,  first let us  eliminate $y$ term, for this let us multiply first equation  by $5$ and  second  one by $7$, we will get

$${25x+35y}\equiv 6\pmod {9}.$$

$${42x+35y}\equiv 1\pmod {9}.$$

Now subtract, we will get 
$${17x}\equiv {-5}\pmod {9},$$

which is the same as
$${17x}\equiv {4}\pmod {9}.$$

I found multiplicative inverse of  $17$ and  $9$   which is equal to  $8$, so I got

\begin{align*}
{17\cdot 8 x}&\equiv {4\cdot 8}\pmod {9}\\
{x}&\equiv {32}\pmod {9},
\end{align*}

and the last one  reduces to

$${x}\equiv {5}\pmod {9}.$$

Now let us insert this equation to the first one

\begin{align*}
{5\cdot 5+7y}&\equiv 3\pmod {9}\\
{7y}&\equiv {-22} \pmod {9},
\end{align*}

which is the same as
$${y}\equiv {-88} \pmod {9}$$

or

$${y}\equiv {2} \pmod {9}.$$

So, my final solution is

$${x}\equiv {5}\pmod {9},$$

$${y}\equiv {2} \pmod {9}.$$

Am I  right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain the bit about multiplicative inverse?  i don't quite understand it

Comment: for instance for  $17$ and  $9$ right ,   we should find such kind of  $x$ so that $${17*x}\equiv {1} \pmod {9}.$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I don't think my maths is advanced enough to be certain, but your solution appears to be correct

Comment: good night , i am  also learning many things,  life is study